# filter dataset not having a value

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

Suppose i have a schema like below :

```
Book | Author
-------------
 B1  |   A1
 B1  |   A3
 B1  |   A2

 B2  |   A5 
 B2  |   A4
 B2  |   A3

 B3  |   A5
 B3  |   A6
 B3  |   A1

 B4  |   A1
 B4  |   A5
 B4  |   A6
```

with below model:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name=_('authors'),
    )
    book = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name=_('book'),
    )

    book_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default="regular"
    )

    flavour = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name=_('flavour'),
    )
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
```

and i want to filter out all those book whose author is *not* A1 (*B2 in this case*)

This is simple SQL using `group by` and `not having` clause, what i am having tough time is getting it done usinng django queryset and annotate. Most of the annotate work around `count` which i am not able to fit in this particular case.

any pointers is helpful, thanks! :)

Comment: Can you post the Django models?

Comment: @solarissmoke : added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Books.objects.exclude(author='A1')
```

If you want a distinct list of `book` values then you can do:

```
Books.objects.exclude(author='A1').values_list('book').distinct()
```

Your `Books` model looks a little strange to me though. Not sure what your specific use case is, but it seems that a `Book` model with a `ManyToMany` relationship to an `Author` might be more appropriate.

Comment: its a legacy model, when this table was supposed to contain everything...no normalisation .... *sins of our forefathers kind of hurt here*! :)