# Django queryset: Exclude all row(s) if any one row with same id is excluded

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am using Django query to filter out some transactions from table where one transaction might have multiple entries in the table.

E.g. Sample table

```
+---------------+---------+
| TransactionId | Status  |
+---------------+---------+
| Txn0          | Pending |
| Txn0          | Success |
| Txn1          | Fail    |
| Txn2          | Pending |
| Txn3          | Fail    |
| Txn4          | Pending |
| Txn4          | Fail    |
| Txn5          | Pending |
+---------------+---------+
```

Current query :

```
SampleTable.objects.exclude(status='Fail').exclude(status='Success')
```

My current query returns `Txn0`, `Txn2`,`Txn4`, `Txn5`( because these are marked pending).

I need a queryset which return only row `Txn2`, `Txn5`( because all other transaction has atleast one Fail or Success transaction).

Also, tried using `.distinct()` but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you add details about how you tried to use `distinct`? It seems like exactly what you need.

Comment: [something on similar lines...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842758/filter-dataset-not-having-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not a straight one. But, first filter all the transactions(row) with Failed/success status.

```
success_fail_txns = SampleTable.objects.filter(status='Success') 
                       | SampleTable.objects.filter(status='Fail')
pending_txns = SampleTable.objects.exclude(txnid__in=success_fail_txns)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **exclude with in** condition

```
SampleTable.objects.exclude(status__in=['Fail','Success'])
```

Comment: you need ' around Success :)

Comment: Although this is correct, it does not solve OP's problem. i.e. - it would give the same results as the code he posted above.

Comment: Agree @MrName. This solution posted is similar to the query I am using.